# How to convert json unicoded value to other font's unicode?

Tags: android, json, unicode, fonts, encode

I have data with local font in my database. I can extract it successfully in php (displaying the same local word in webpage). Now, I want to send this data using JSON so that it can be accessed by Android app. While encoding in JSON, is it possible to encode in different font's unicode?

After retrieving JSON encoded values, the word can be displayed in font A (but in broken format). But I want to show it using font B (so that broken stuffs are solved in this).

So, is there any way to encode using different font so that I can fix my issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there any way to encode using different font so that I can fix my issue ?

No. Unicode strings contain only plain semantic text. There are no markup constructs in it that would allow you to choose a different font; that has to be provided by a layer above text such as HTML.

> the word can be displayed in font A (but in broken format). But I want to show it using font B (so that broken stuffs are solved in this).

The app that consumes the JSON and displays data from it must be altered to display using Font B.

Note that Android support for Indic scripts has historically been notoriously poor and still suffers from bugs; prior to the 4.x series you will probably be missing any kind of Font B or even correct Devenagari glyph layout.

Comment: thanx for clearing out. i'm still in problem with Font A missing glyphs in GB 2.3 and so. And font B totally missing. Any idea ?

Comment: If it's your app, you can bundle Font B with it to render the glyphs in a basic fashion. But you will never get proper Indic complex text layout in Gingerbread, which makes it pretty much a dead loss for Hindi.

Comment: :( When I bundle Font B (which doesn't break) and use it for the text, all I get is rectangles instead of text. (the unicode is different for 2 different fonts.) The unicode I have only displays broken texts for Font A.

Comment: There is only one Unicode. What is Font B? Maybe you have a “visual” non-Unicode symbol font (ie like Wingdings, except with each letter being displayed as a pre-rendered combined Devenagari glyph instead of wacky shapes)? In that case you could display the right glyphs by doing your own mapping from Unicode to arbitrary-symbols, but it would be a real pain and the text wouldn't interoperate with anything else on the system.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, JSON must be encoded in UTF-8.

When you talk about font, I assume you are talking about encoding - text by itself does not specify which font will be used to render it on user screen. Best option is to always store your data in UTF-8, so you don't have to recode anything. All open-source databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) provide a way to store text in UTF-8 by default. Also, Android uses UTF-8 by default for all strings (JSON, XML, etc).

If you data is encoded in some legacy encoding (like CP1250 or CP1251), your should use appropriate method to convert that encoding into UTF-8 before creating JSON. Almost every platform provides a way for such conversion. One of the popular libraries for this is [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) (it has bindings for PHP, C/C++, etc), but I am sure there are many other ways to accomplish that.

Comment: Yeah, I have my data stored in UTF8_General_ci format. I have only problem with the unicode value. For example, JSON encode is giving me value like \u0930\u093e\ for certain word. Instead I want this word in 'Font ABC' whose corresponding unicode would be 's v'.

Comment: It seems like JSON encoder decided to use surrogate pair encoding. Can you tell exactly what is your problem word? How does it look like from MySQL side, or better yet what is exact byte sequence is it?

Comment: Suppose my word is पूर्ण. This word is well stored in my database and also well shown in my webpage. JSON encoded gives me unicode value like \u0930\u9876. But this code when used in my app using Font ABC shows up in broken form like प् ुर् . 
And like said earlier, Font XYZ will show this word all good in app which has its unicode value like 'r 5 h em'.

Comment: Your JSON encoder seems to be broken. I can create `test.json` with this content in UTF-8 just fine: `{"x": "पूर्ण"}`, hexdump: `7B 22 78 22 3A 20 22 E0 A4 AA E0 A5 82 E0 A4 B0 E0 A5 8D E0 A4 A3 22 7D`

Comment: Why not? But again, there is no such thing as "font" for text in UTF-8 or any other encoding. Font is simply numbered set of pictograms that can be used to render your text visually. That set may lack some "numbers", thus will be unable to display certain characters.

Comment: mvp, can u guide me on how to create hex dump of the unicode and use for other font ? i m using php/mysql for json creation and java (for android) to convert and show the word.